2-VASS reachability algorithm
I am trying to implement 2-VASS (Vector addition system with states) reachability algorithm from this research paper. I understand the theory but somehow I am unable to code it down. Can anyone help me with it.

This post is off-topic on this site, whose topic is Theoretical Computer Science, whereas your question is the opposite (taking an existing TCS result and working out the engineering aspects). Moreover, "help me with it" is not a specific question with a definite answer.
